# Is it considered safe to suspend/hibernate a computer while it's compiling some code?

Tags: hibernate, make, gcc, suspend

Will it continue the process where left off? I'm using gcc on a GNU/Linux machine.

Comment: No; it won't continue where you left off.

Comment: @ramhound Do you have a source for that?